# Union of masked values

Tags: sql-server, ssms, tabular

I've got a problem with making union of 2 tables that have values masked using random function. Unless someone has permission to read all data, user should see random values between (-1000,2000)

making separate views for each table generates the values in a correct way, however there's problem when I try to make union of those 2 tables or views. Instead of seeing random values I see 0 for everything

Let's say there's table A defined as:

```
ID      INT       IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
Value   MONEY     MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'random(-1000, 20000)') NOT NULL
```

and table B as:

```
ID      INT       IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
Value   DECIMAL   (18, 6) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'random(-1000.000000, 20000.000000)') NULL
```

in table A:

```
ID   Value
1     12
2     21
3     34
```

in table B:

```
ID   Value
7     17.12
8     23.01
9     2.56
```

view on each of table shows ID's of each tables and masked values for user without permissions and values as in table for user with permissions which is correct

however UNION of both tables should show ID's and masked values but instead it shows values = 0.000000.

I'm kinda confused on how to make those values appear as masked random values in union

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `UNION` / `UNION ALL` a select of the same table without problems. But using two different tables gives 0 for all masked values.

You can use the following as a workaround using temporary tables:

```
SELECT * INTO #t1 FROM TableA
SELECT * INTO #t2 FROM TableB

SELECT * FROM #t1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM #t2
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=833b90cedb11580bfdc761776442394b)